# Call a method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am new in Phonegap and JavaScript. I want call a method from JavaScript in android side and send lat and long from android to JS. but i don't understand how can i send this method in sendJavaScript() because i don't understand this declare method in JS side. anyway if you know please help me how can send this method. Thanks

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("#my-map").kmap({
    mapLayer: 'GoogleMap.RoadMap',
    contentRoot: "Content/Images/Markers/"
});

$("#my-map").kmap("addMarkers", [{
    lat: 35.677336572709514,
    lng: 51.41564316503603,
    id: 0
}]);
var l = 51.41564316503603;

var animate = function () {
    l += 0.00001;
    $("#my-map").kmap("repositionMarker", 0, [35.677336572709514, l]);
    setTimeout(animate, 500);
};
animate();
});
</script>
```

and android side:

```
public class GPScls extends DroidGap{
public void GPS(double lat,double lng){
    this.sendJavascript("javascript:$("+lat+","+lng+")");
}
}
```

Comment: Check this http://www.jumpbyte.com/2012/phonegap-native-to-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I see this link but i think this is not my answer, because i call JS function like this link but i don't know when my JS function declare like above($function(){$(){};${}}), how can call this?Thanks